# Lambda function error - Failed to assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

How do we make sure lambda function able to make changes on other AWS accounts, I have added trust policy in other accounts but still getting error " Failed to assume role" when running lambda function. Is it possible that SCP restricting access to other accounts from Lambda functions?

I tried to add assume role and trust relation policy on account but still getting failed to assume role when running lambda function. Kindly help me.

Comment: What policy? You haven't show any in your question.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/.      I followed this article and updated policies but still getting failed to assume role, I am wondering if there is any SCP which restricts assume role

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two IAM roles, the first in the target account and the second in the source account where your lambda resides. Only the IAM role of the source account where you allow the assumption of the IAM role of the target account should be associated with the Lambda.

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<target account>:role/<role name in target account>"
```

[Here is a fairly simple workshop on configuring a cross-account lambda to list buckets](https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/300_labs/300_lambda_cross_account_iam_role_assumption/)

Comment: I tried to follow this and got below error.   An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::Account1:assumed-role/Lambda-Assume-Roles/Lambda-Assume-Roles is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::Account2:role/LambdaS3ListBuckets

Comment: Without seeing your code or getting any additional infos to your accounts configuration I'm not sure what exactly caused this error. [You might need to troubleshoot  your configurations again](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-error/#:~:text=Bob%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Action%22%3A%20%22sts%3AAssumeRole%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D-,Resolution,-To%20avoid%20errors)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. Something related to my code. Thanks.